# How to find the arc centre and radius given the arc start point and arc end point and arc direction?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line, arc-length, mathcad

I know the arc start point and the end point. It is separated by a height/distance as shown in the figure.The blue line end points are the arc start and end points respectively. How can i drawn a arc given that I dont know either its centre nor radius. Is there a method to do this? please let me know.[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIqvy.jpg)
Thank you

Comment: I don’t see no figure.

Comment: I have added the link

Comment: There are lots of similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217731/given-an-arc-mid-point-length-and-radius-how-do-we-find-the-start-and-end-poi). Look through the links first and then come back if you have any more questions.

Comment: there are questions where arc centre/ radius and start point is known. Only one unknown variable. But here I have only two known parameters and two unknown parameters.

Comment: the number of arcs passing two points is infinite, for a certain arc you need to know the height, the distance between two points does not help.

Comment: The center of the arc can be anywhere on the perpendicular bisector of the blue segment. Each choice of the center will give a possible arc.